# What's the best way to set different View Value and Model Value in Vue2?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a use case where I need to show a value different from the model value.
It's an Autocomplete where when the user selects a value, I want to show a custom template which has user's image, email and address whereas the actual model value should be Email Address only.

I Angular, I could have achieved this using Parser & Formatter but couldn't find any such thing in Vue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code with an attempt? Something for us to start with.

Comment: You need email, image and name in the model in order to get those values.

Comment: [Computed Properties](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)?